# How to use System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a))

Tags: java, eclipse

How to use it and an example with that please. Thanks! If you could also, I want a program that prints an array. I can't do it beaucause it makes me an error, and I want to know if I do something wrong.
Is that code right??
import java.util.Arrays;

kk

I get this:
I
I
[[I@e53108, [I@f62373]I
I
[[I@e53108, [I@f62373]
Osama, when I run your code, there pop ups an error box which says java exception and prints many errors.

Osama, your code when I run it says java Exception in an error box

Comment: This might be the laziest request I have seen on SO. Why don't you do it yourself?

Comment: (i) create an array and call it `a` (ii) run `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a))`

Comment: If you get an error: show your code and the error...

Comment: _"How to use it and an example with that please."_ - I would look at this question title for a good example. It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

> I get this: I I [[I@e53108, [I@f62373]I I [[I@e53108, [I@f62373]

This is because you are printing a multi-dimensional array. For this, you can use [`Arrays#deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(a));
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I was too busy downvoting all the wrong answers.

Answer (score -1):

A simple program to print an Array of string values

```
public class PrintArray{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         String[] array = {"a","b","c","d"};
         for(String s : array)
               System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

the output:-

```
a
b
c
d
```

I hope it's useful for you.